# Digital Mars Compiler (Code::Blocks) unable to open file 'iostream'

Tags: c++, codeblocks, iostream

I'm starting to code in Code::Blocks and I need a compiler, I  installed Digital Mars at C:/dm and selected it in Code:Blocks. The sc.ini of C:/dm/bin looks like this:

```
    [Version]
version=7.51 Build 020

[Environment]
PATH=%PATH%;"%@P%\..\bin"
BIN="%@P%\..\bin"
INCLUDE="%@P%\..\stlport\stlport";"%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include"
;%INCLUDE%
;INCLUDE="%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%
LIB="%@P%\..\lib";"%@P%\..\mfc\lib";%LIB%
HELP="%@P%\..\help"
```

but when compiling I always get this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Serevr (compiler: Digital Mars Compiler) ===|
||unable to open input file 'iostream'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I looked at other posts but none helped! does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the file has been edited by you. `BIN` and `INCLUDE` will most likely not work if on the same line - insert a newline before `INCLUDE`:

```
BIN="%@P%\..\bin"
INCLUDE="%@P%\..\stlport\stlport";"%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%
;INCLUDE="%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%`
```

and try again.

Also, did you download and install the STLport? As the `iostream` header comes from there for DM. Check also the stlport include, the `"%@P%\..\stlport\stlport"` entry seems somewhat dubious - depending where you installed it, it could be only `"%@P%\..\stlport"` (i.e. check if the `iostream` header is really in the `C:\DM\stlport\stlport` or just in `C:\DM\stlport` or maybe even in `C:\DM\stlport\include` or somewhere alike).

Besides, the Digital Mars compiler could be somewhat tricky in my experience (e.g. not supported by CMake AFAIK), you might want to try the MinGW (GCC) compiler, which is more up to date and likely better supported by various tools.

(or the MS Visual Studio Express, which is native on Windows and comes with the IDE)

Comment: Sorry about any confusion but INCLUDE is on a new line, while adding code to the post I failed to fix that, though that is not the issue, Ill fix that now to stop any other confusions, I tried MinGW (GCC) But that would not work either.

Comment: Updated. Also check the STLport installation and location.

Comment: It has worked! stl port had been extracted to C:/dm/stlport not C:/dm/stlport/stlport! Thank you its working properly now!